# How to move uncommitted changes to Head to a branch and then reset the Head to the original state in SVN?

Tags: svn

I created a local copy of a large OS project. I was just dabbling so I did not bother with branching . Anyway I ended up making some changes to the source and created an extension for it. Now I have not committed anything back in my local(so it is at Head with modifications). I realize that I would like to move my changes to a branch and then reset the HEAD to the whatever the original version was or the current state of the project from their servers.

How can I move all the changes that are sitting at Head in a uncommitted stage to a branch to make further modifications? And Then I would like to reset the Head to premodif state or the current state from the server. Once all moved in place I am going to create a proper patch against the current Head from the project.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, svn isn't a distributed system, so there is no concept of a local HEAD and remote HEAD. Rather, there is one, canonical HEAD, known as trunk in svn parlance.

As to your question, you create an svn branch through the [copy command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.using.html) with two remote URLs. Then things proceed as you'd expect.

1. copy myWorkingCopy myWorkingCopyBackup
2. checkout a new version from remote
3. make myWorkingCopy an instance of your new branch
4. copy myWorkingCopyBackup to myWorkingCopy, replacing everything aside from the .svn directory
5. checkin

You should now be golden, with your changes checked into your new branch and a pristine trunk

Comment: Thanks, however I am using TortoiseSvn so when I tried branching in it, it warned me that I have uncommitted changes and I  will loose changes. Are you suggesting that those changes have to be committed to be able to copy/branch?

Comment: Yes, or moved to another directory.

Comment: Well the problem is that it seems like the commits will be done to the central server as far as I can tell. THat is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

1. select "create branch"

   - as branch source use "HEAD", "not working copy"
   - enable "switch to the branch" checkbox (at the bottom of the dialog)
2. create the branch

Now you have working copy of a branch created from trunk and your changes ready for committing into that branch. No modifications of trunk.